# $CLASSPATH en ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar

Esto establece la ruta de clase para el terminal. Si cierro esa ventana de terminal y comienzo una nueva ventana de terminal, actualmente tengo que despedir comando para establecer ruta de clase. Quiero configurarlo para que sea permanente. ¿Cómo puedo conseguir esto?

Answer (score 1):

Las variables de ambiente se heredan de padre a hijo. Si abres un shell (bash) en una terminal en un entorno gráfico, este shell es hijo del proceso que corre el entorno gráfico. Por lo tanto cualquier variable de ambiente que definas o cambies en tu terminal solo se verá en esa terminal y en procesos hijos de ese shell.

Si quieres que una modificación de una variable de ambiente sea "global" y/o "persistente", hay varias alternativas según tu escenario.

Una es setear la variable en el arhivo de inicialización del usuario que abrirá la terminal. Por ejemplo, en `~/.profile`
Estos seteos se aplicarán cada vez que el usuario abre un nuevo shell (en terminal gráfica o no).

La otra es setear la variable globalmente, a nivel sistema. Esto puede hacerse (en Ubuntu y varios otros Linux) en los archivos
  `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`
o 
 `/etc/environment`

Para detalles, mira la documentación (en inglés) [aquí](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables).